# Can't properly set up next-config storybook to get images from url

Tags: webpack, next.js, storybook

I'm trying to import an image from an url in storybook. In nextJS, images can't come from a domain unless you allow it.
I allowed it in the `next-config.js` file doing the following:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    API: process.env.API
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['https://sourceexample.com/image']
  }
};
```

It works for when making pages outside of storybook, with the regular `next dev`. However, when I try to render the same page that has this component:

```js
      <Image
       alt="example"
       src="https://sourceexample.com/image.png"
       width="auto"
       height="auto"
     />
```

It shows the exact same error when I didn't add the allowed domain in `next-config.js`, which is:
`` Invalid src prop (https://sourceexample.com/image.png) on `next/image`, hostname "source" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js ``

I thought that maybe it was because I should import `next-config.js`into storybook configurations, so I google for it and stumbled upon this piece of code, which I don't know what to do with it. This code is written under **"How do I setup Storybook to share Webpack configuration with Next.js?"** in the storyboook documentation.

```js
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (baseConfig) => {
    const nextConfig = require('/path/to/next.config.js');

    // merge whatever from nextConfig into the webpack config storybook will use
    return { ...baseConfig };
  },
```

I tried making a spread of the properties in `nextConfig` like adding
`return {...baseConfig, ...nextConfig}` in the return method. It didn't work. Can someone explain what is happening here and how am I supposed to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add this code to the `.storybook/preview.js` file:

```js
import * as nextImage from 'next/image';

Object.defineProperty(nextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: props => <img {...props} />
});
```

**Update**: seems that this addon fixes the issue - https://storybook.js.org/addons/storybook-addon-next

Comment: This only bypasses the error, but it does not uses the Image tag properly, right? I tried removing the host in the config, and still worked

Comment: Yes, it's just a workaround

Comment: The addon works fine for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue and solved it by mocking 'next/image' in storybook's webpack config (see details at the link below)

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/workflows/build-pages-with-storybook#mocking-imports

Create a new React component file:

```
// file: .storybook/__mocks__/NextJSImageMock.js

import React from "react";

export default function NextImageMock(props) {
  return <img {...props} />;
}
```

Then, overwrite the import:

```
// file: .storybook/webpack.config.js

module.exports = ({ config }) => {
  config.resolve.alias = {
    "next/image": require.resolve("./__mocks__/NextJSImageMock.js"),
  };

  return config;
};
```