# How to get Next Image component working with Storybook

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

I'm trying to follow [this](https://dev.to/alexeagleson/how-to-build-scalable-architecture-for-your-nextjs-project-2pb7) tutorial and have come across an issue where I can not load the CatCard component which is using the NextJs Image component

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from './CatCard.module.css';

export interface ICatCard {
  tag: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  author: string;
  time: string;
}

const CatCard: React.FC<ICatCard> = ({ tag, title, body, author, time }) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.card}>
        <div className={styles.card__header}>
          <Image
            src="/time-cat.jpg"
            alt="card__image"
            className={styles.card__image}
            width="600"
            height="400"
          />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.card__body}>
          <span className={`${styles.tag} ${styles['tag-blue']}`}>{tag}</span>
          <h4>{title}</h4>
          <p>{body}</p>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.card__footer}>
          <div className={styles.user}>
            <Image
              src="https://i.pravatar.cc/40?img=3"
              alt="user__image"
              className={styles.user__image}
              width="40"
              height="40"
            />
            <div className={styles.user__info}>
              <h5>{author}</h5>
              <small>{time}</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CatCard;
```

I've tried to update the next.config.js file as suggested when following this error when trying to run this

```
Invalid src prop (https://i.pravatar.cc/40?img=3) on `next/image`, hostname "i.pravatar.cc" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info:
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: ['i.pravatar.cc'],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And I've tried to add the storybook-addon-next addon for storybook per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67409774/cant-properly-set-up-next-config-storybook-to-get-images-from-url)

with no luck.

preview.js for storybook

```
import * as NextImage from 'next/image';
import '../styles/globals.css';

const BREAKPOINTS_INT = {
  xs: 375,
  sm: 600,
  md: 900,
  lg: 1200,
  xl: 1536,
};

const customViewports = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(BREAKPOINTS_INT).map(([key, val], idx) => {
    console.log(val);
    return [
      key,
      {
        name: key,
        styles: {
          width: `${val}px`,
          height: `${(idx + 5) * 10}vh`,
        },
      },
    ];
  })
);

// Allow Storybook to handle Next's <Image> component
const OriginalNextImage = NextImage.default;

Object.defineProperty(NextImage, 'default', {
  configurable: true,
  value: (props) => <OriginalNextImage {...props} unoptimized />,
});

export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: '^on[A-Z].*' },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
  viewport: { viewports: customViewports },
};
```

main.js for storybook

```
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../**/*.stories.mdx', '../**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  /** Expose public folder to storybook as static */
  staticDirs: ['../public'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    'storybook-addon-next',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-webpack5',
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a VARIABLE src then pass it through a "loader"

```
import Image from 'next/image';
import styles from './CatCard.module.css';

export interface ICatCard {
  tag: string;
  title: string;
  body: string;
  author: string;
  time: string;
}
const CatCard: React.FC<ICatCard> = ({ tag, title, body, author, time }) => {
  const srcGuy = `https://i.pravatar.cc/40?img=3`;
  const srcCat = '/time-cat.jpg';
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div className={styles.card}>
        <div className={styles.card__header}>
          <Image
            loader={() => srcCat}
            src={srcCat}
            width={600}
            height={400}
            alt="card__image"
          />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.card__body}>
          <span className={`${styles.tag} ${styles['tag-blue']}`}>{tag}</span>
          <h4>{title}</h4>
          <p>{body}</p>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.card__footer}>
          <div className={styles.user}>
            <Image
              loader={() => srcGuy}
              src={srcGuy}
              width={40}
              height={40}
              alt="user__image"
              className={styles.user__image}
            />
            <div className={styles.user__info}>
              <h5>{author}</h5>
              <small>{time}</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CatCard;
```